# Corona SDK 'attempt to index a nil value' on a jpeg

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have made an app which uses a large number of preloaded jpegs. I have built it and when I tried to launch it on my galaxy tab, it gives me this error:

`C:\users\user\desktop\myapp\Myapp\main.lua:12:attempt to index local "image.jpg"(a nil value)`

```
local pic1 = display.newImage("img/pic1.jpg",
     display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY)
pic1:scale(1.38, 1.10)         <------------error here
pic1.isVisible = false

buttonpic1= display.newRect(85,490,130,190)
buttonpic1:addEventListener("touch", pic1ButtonEvent)
buttonpic1.isVisible = false
buttonpic1.isHitTestable = true
buttonpic1.alpha = 0.3
```

Basically it's an invisible button on a mapm when clicked it opens a part of it

That image is the second one in my code so the first is loaded correctly.

Comment: can you show the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: Ok, I added the code to your question,. Could you edit your question to show the line that causes the error `-- error message`.

Comment: Can you `assert(pic1)` and make sure it doesn't fail after doing a `display.newImage`?

Comment: I dont find any problem with the above code, more over in the above code you are not using any local image, so kindly paste the remaining code.

Comment: Are you using any image named `image.jpg` inside your class? Then make sure the image resides inside your project folder.  Also make sure your image name, case and`extension are correct.